# Part of JSON response from server is returning null: Android

Tags: android, arrays, json, android-json

I am trying to fetch data from the server and then display it into the app.
I have JSON data as,

```
{"COLUMNS":["TIMEID","BRANCHID","COMPANYID","MON_O","TUE_O","WED_O","THU_O","FRI_O","SAT_O","SUN_O","MON_C","TUE_C","WED_C","THU_C","FRI_C","SAT_C","SUN_C","CREATDATE"],"DATA":[[195,4,4,"09:00","09:00","09:00","09:00","09:00","Closed","Closed","16:30","16:30","16:30","16:30","16:30","Closed","Closed","May, 16 2017 08:16:12"]]}
```

When I access the url I get the complete JSON Data but when I am logging the same response from the server, I am not getting the DATA part of the JSON data.

My JAVA class implementation is as,

```
public static final String MON_O  = "MON_O";
public static final String TUE_O = "TUE_O";
public static final String WED_O = "WED_O";
public static final String THU_O = "THU_O";
public static final String FRI_O = "FRI_O";
public static final String SAT_O = "SAT_O";
public static final String SUN_O = "SUN_O";

public static final String MON_C = "MON_C";
public static final String TUE_C = "TUE_C";
public static final String WED_C = "WED_C";
public static final String THU_C = "THU_C";
public static final String FRI_C = "FRI_C";
public static final String SAT_C = "SAT_C";
public static final String SUN_C = "SUN_C";

public static final String JSON_ARRAY = "COLUMNS";

private void getData() {
String url =      context.getString(site_url)+"branch_time.cfc?method=branchtime&branchid=" +dBranchID;

StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(url, new Response.Listener<String>() {

    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {
        showJSON(response);
    }
},
        new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(context,error.getMessage().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}

private void showJSON(String response) {

String name = "";

try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
        JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray(JSON_ARRAY);
        Log.d("TAG", result.toString());

        name = result.getString(MON_O);
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

 timeStatus.setText(name);
}
```

I am trying to log the result from the server and getting the below,

```
  ["TIMEID","BRANCHID","COMPANYID","MON_O","TUE_O","WED_O","THU_O","FRI_O","SAT_O","SUN_O","MON_C","TUE_C","WED_C","THU_C","FRI_C","SAT_C","SUN_C","CREATDATE"]
```

The DATA part of the response is null and I can get only the COLUMNS value.
I have no idea why this could happen. Please can anyone help in this?

Comment: #try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44580161/json-data-parsing-error-the-response-from-server-becomes-null-android/44580614#44580614

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it's null because you never did this to get that data correctly

```
JSONArray companyData = jsonObject.getJSONArray("DATA");
```

You only got the COLUMNS array, and the data is not within that array.

Also note that data array is an array within an array

Comment: When U do JSONArray companyData=jsonObject.getJSONArray("DATA");
 Log.d("TAG", companyData.toString()); I returns null.

Comment: returns null, or throws an exception? There's a large difference. You can use `optJSONArray()` if you are not guaranteed data

Comment: When I log the companyData I get D/TAG: []

Comment: Okay, that's an empty array... Not null

Comment: As I explained too, you have an array in an array. I assume those are rows of a table, in which case, I'd highly recommend rewriting the web API to give you more readable JSON and not keep as if it's still in a SQL database

Comment: ya sorry my mistake... so why I am I getting an empty array? Can u please suggest a way to use the same web API and not get the DATA empty?

Comment: I can't access your API. My answer should be correct for the JSON you've provided

Comment: After following your answer, I still get the DATA array as empty and can't find any way to get the data.

Comment: It works for me with the exact JSON you posted in the question

Comment: Yes I managed to work get the DATA but the issue is if I do                     MON_O = result.getString(0); I am getting the whole DATA as one complete string.

Comment: I don't know what result is there, but `getString(0)` obviously isn't correct. You have an array within an array. If you called to get a String, of course you get that first list as an entire string

Answer (score 0):

Code use for COLUMNS will be:

```
        JSONObject companyData = jsonObject.getJSONArray("COLUMNS");
```

Code use for DATA will be:

```
        JSONObject companyData = jsonObject.getJSONArray("DATA ");
```

Please mark my answer useful, if you get you desired solution.